# Best Way To Import Data from Big-query

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have API  which Insert a data into Big-query table `every hour`, I want to import result of this query to other data source MYSQL, what could low latency solution of this, my data size is around `5GB` each run

One way i thought to get query result and insert into mysql via JDBC , but in memory will not feasible

Comment: Why would you write a program for it? GCP has services to transfer data efficiently at scale, like dataflow or cloud data fusion. You really do not want to write an ETL solution from scratch!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/connect-to-sql) as it is a low latency database. It can run MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQL.

[Export](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#bq) your data from BigQuery using a `CSV file` and store it in `Cloud Storage`. Then, Cloud SQL will import the CSV file from the Cloud Storage. Please also refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export) for import and export best practices.

[Replication](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery) is also another way and it uses `Cloud Data Fusion`.